# Draw (shapes) to a texture/sprite in libGDX

Tags: libgdx

In my libGDX game I have several sprites that share the same texture. Now I want to "manually" draw onto some of the sprites (i.e. I want to change some of the pixels in some of the sprites).

How can I modify a texture that is shared amongst seveal sprites without affecting other sprites?
I guess I need to copy the texture before I set it to the sprite?

Comment: Have you tried using [Pixmaps](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Pixmaps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom shader to customize sprite texture.

Before drawing the sprite with spriteBatch, simply say:

```
spriteBatch.begin();

spriteBatch.useShader(shaderProgram1);
sprite1.draw(...);
spriteBatch.useShader(shaderProgram);
sprite2.draw(...);

...

spriteBatch.end();
```

If you aren't familiar with the shaders you can check this link:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Shaders

Also there is option to use frame buffer object, for texture customization, but I think if those texture difference aren't that huge, this is the best solution if you are looking for best performances.

Hope that this gives you an idea.